# Show data with hyphen (-), if row not found in a table - php

Tags: php, laravel

I don't know either title match the problem exactly but here is my scenario. I am trying to show business hours of a rink in a table. Currently, it is showing as:

```
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>Days</th>
        <th>Opening Time</th>
        <th>Closing Time</th>
    </tr>
    <?php
        $days_arr = ['','Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
        unset($days_arr[0]);

    foreach($rink->businessHours as $hk => $hv){
        for($i=1;$i<8;$i++){
            if($hv->days == $i){

    ?>
            <tr>
                <td>{{$days_arr[$i]}}</td>
                <td>{{$hv->opening_time}}</td>
                <td>{{$hv->closing_time}}</td>
            </tr>
    <?php
            }
        }
    }
    ?>
</tbody>
```

Which is currently showing as:

[image: Screenshot]

But, here as you can see there is not any row for `Thu` and `Sun`. Now, I want to show that row as well with something like as follows:

```
Thu | - | - |
Sun | - | - |
```

Currently, that `$rink->businessHours` contain data something like:

```
Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection Object
(
    [items:protected] => Array
        (
            [0] => App\Models\BusinessHours Object
                (

                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 19
                            [days] => 1
                            [opening_time] => 07:00AM
                            [closing_time] => 08:00PM
                            [timezone] => MST
                            [rink_id] => 4
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                            [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                        )

                )

            [1] => App\Models\BusinessHours Object
                (
                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 20
                            [days] => 2
                            [opening_time] => 07:00AM
                            [closing_time] => 08:00PM
                            [timezone] => MST
                            [rink_id] => 4
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                            [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                        )

                )

            [2] => App\Models\BusinessHours Object
                (

                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 21
                            [days] => 3
                            [opening_time] => 07:00AM
                            [closing_time] => 08:00PM
                            [timezone] => MST
                            [rink_id] => 4
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                            [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                        )

                )

            [3] => App\Models\BusinessHours Object
                (

                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 23
                            [days] => 5
                            [opening_time] => 07:00AM
                            [closing_time] => 08:00PM
                            [timezone] => MST
                            [rink_id] => 4
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                            [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                        )

                )

            [4] => App\Models\BusinessHours Object
                (

                    [attributes:protected] => Array
                        (
                            [id] => 24
                            [days] => 6
                            [opening_time] => 07:00AM
                            [closing_time] => 01:00PM
                            [timezone] => MST
                            [rink_id] => 4
                            [created_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                            [updated_at] => 2019-07-25 06:00:54
                        )


                )

)
```

Comment: is there any reason why your `$days_arr` doesn't start with `Mon` at index `0` ? Forcing you to do `for ($i = 1` instead of `for ($i = 0` ?

Comment: It's just because I have saved these day in database starting from day 1-7 as Mon-Sun

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This creates an array containing the opening hours first and then displays this array.  The hours is first created with all of the days and the opening and closing times as '-', then for each of the actual opening times, these overwrite the dummy values.  This means that any missing days will display with those dummy values...

```
$days_arr = [ 1=> 'Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];
$hours = array_fill(1, 7, ['opening_time' => '-', 'closing_time' => '-']);
foreach ( $rink->businessHours as $hk => $hv){
    $hours[$hv->days] = ['opening_time' => $hv->opening_time, 
        'closing_time' => $hv->closing_time];
}
```

and then to display...

```
foreach($hours as $hk => $hv){
?>
    <tr>
        <td>{{$days_arr[$hk]}}</td>
        <td>{{$hv['opening_time']}}</td>
        <td>{{$hv['closing_time']</td>
    </tr>
<?php
}
```

Note that with the day array, you can say start the key at 1 rather than having to add an empty value and then delete it.  Also that your last `for` loop wasn't needed as you an directly access the days array using `$days_arr[$hk]`.

Comment: Other than a small typo, `{{$hv['closing_time']` here missing `}}` all other seems fine. Thank you, Nigel

Answer (score 0):

You can use the else block after your if statement to just add in a blank entry.

```
<tr>
    <td>{{$days_arr[$i]}}</td>
    <td>&mdash</td>
    <td>&mdash</td>
</tr>
```

This will create a long dash entry for those days.

You might also want to create your $days_arr without the first blank entry. Instead of unsetting the first entry just + 1 to $i in your loop.

```
$days_arr = ['Mon', 'Tue', 'Wed', 'Thu', 'Fri', 'Sat', 'Sun'];


foreach($rink->businessHours as $hk => $hv){
    for($i=0; $i<7; $i++){
        if($hv->days == $i + 1){
```